# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

I am creating **UIButton** dynamically in the **FOR** loop as follows :

```
     CGRect workingFrame = imgscrollView.frame;
      workingFrame.origin.x = 0;
      workingFrame.origin.y = 0;

   for (int i=0 ; i < self.currentDetails.arrayOfImages.count ; i++)
   {
    UIButton *imageBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [imageBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imageBtn setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    imageBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    imageBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    imageBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    imageBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageBtn.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [imageBtn setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [imageBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageBtn setTag:i];
    [imgscrollView addSubview:imageBtn];

     imageBtn.frame = CGRectMake(workingFrame.origin.x+20, workingFrame.origin.y, 145, 140);
   }
```

But at the time of setting its frame

**imageBtn.frame = CGRectMake(workingFrame.origin.x+20, workingFrame.origin.y, 145, 140);**

i am getting following error and it crashes :

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

I have searched for this but could not get the solution.

Please help me.

Thanks...

Comment: Valid stack trace please?

Comment: Which exact line causes the crash?

Comment: as an aside, if you are getting your scroll view's `frame` then setting the origin to (0,0) perhaps you should have just retrieved its `bounds` in the first place. Difference between frame and bounds seems oft misunderstood.

Comment: @rmaddy i have updated my question. It is crashing at the time of setting its frame.

Comment: @RobP what should i do? because if try to set static frame like **imageBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 140);** than also it crashes

Comment: The problem may be caused by the `image` you set on the button. Verify that `image` is REALLY a `UIImage` and not actually an `NSString`.

Comment: @Rohan the bug is somewhere else in your code. Where are you creating `image` for example?

Comment: @rmaddy ya you are right. the problem is in the image.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert ya you are right. the problem is in the image.

Comment: thanks for your help. It is solved by setting Image in right way.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size method is there for the classes that are in the image attached

[image]

Since you are using image here check whether you have a proper image instance.